# Dropzone plugin for standard http form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dropzone.js

I want to use **dropzone plugin** to send some files with a standard http form. I don't want to use ajax or asynchronous upload, but I simply need a cool plugin to populate my  fields, after that my form should be sent with its submit button.

I found this:
[Dropzone with normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218552/dropzone-with-normal-form)
But this is not my solution because the processQueue() sends the form as an ajax call.